# How do i re-write this assemly lang.program so that it can double any number passed to it

Tags: assembly, x86, dos

```
;DOUBLE This program prompt the user to enter 
;a number <5,
;doubles the number, and outputs the result

            name    double
            .model  small
            .stack

            .data
prompt      db 0ah,0dh,"Enter a number <5:$"
msg         db 0ah,0dh,"Double your number is :"
result      db ?,0ah,0dh,"$"

            .code
start:
            mov ax,@data
            move ds,ax
            lea dx,prompt
            mov ah,9           ;dos fn to outputstring up to $
            int 21h
            mov ab,1               ;dos fn to input byte into al
            int 21h
            sub al,30h             ;Convert from ascii to single digit integer
            add al,al
            add al,30h             ;Convert back to ascii
            mov result,al
            lea dx,msg
            mov ah,9
            int 21h
            mov ax,4c00h            ;4c in ah is dos exit
            int 21h
            end start
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Even though this is the wrong site for this, it is so poorly formatted we can not migrate it to the correct site. Please take a few minutes to [edit] this question by cleaning it up, formatting it properly and include proper content so we know what you are asking. Simply cutting and pasting code into the question block is unacceptable. If you need assistance, read ***[ask]***.

Comment: Exact duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35467256/unexpected-output-in-a-simple-x86-dos-assembly-program). Guys homeworks are there to help you learn...

Answer (score 0):

Input multiple digit numbers:
Start with 0 then multiply the value you have got so far by ten, add the new digit, repeat for all digits entered.

Output multiple digit number:
Start with an empty string, and repeatedly divide the number by ten; keep the quotient. the remainder of the division tells which digit to PREPEND to the output string. Repeat on the quotient while the value is greater than 0.

Using other base numbers:
Replace "ten" above by the number representing the base.